# Thunderbolt display "disconnects" after 17" MBP 2011 goes to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, macos, thunderbolt-display

My Thunderbolt display was working flawlessly until I upgraded my 2011 17" MBP to OS X 10.9. Now, when the MBP goes to sleep the display will not wake, the MBP wakes fine. The USB drive plugged into the back of the display is disconnected as well.

I have to unplug the thunderbolt cable and plug it back in.

Comment: I would promptly make apple aware of the issue: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macbookpro.html

Comment: I see this issue on my 15-inch, Mid 2012 MacBook Pro as well.